# duda sobre porcentaje en diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio el cuál me pide calcular mediante un diccionario, calcular el porcentaje que aparece los números del 1 al 6 en 10000 tiradas de dados.
Ya tengo un diccionario el cuál me dice cuántas veces aparece cada numero en 10000 tiradas, solo me falta calcular el porcentaje, que no se me ocurre como.
Mi código es el siguiente:

import random

```
def probabilidad():
    dado=random.randint(1,6)
    prob1=0
    prob2=0
    prob3=0
    prob4=0
    prob5=0
    prob6=0
    listavacia=[]
    dicctiradas={}
    for i in range(10000):
        dado=random.randint(1,6)
        print(dado)
        listavacia.append(dado)
    for elem in listavacia:
        if elem==1:
             prob1=prob1+1
        else:
            if elem==2:
                    prob2=prob2+1
            else:
                if elem==3:
                        prob3=prob3+1
                else:
                    if elem==4:
                            prob4=prob4+1
                    else:
                        if elem==5:
                            prob5=prob5+1
                        else:
                            if elem==6:
                                    prob6=prob6+1

    dicctiradas={1:prob1,2:prob2,3:prob3,4:prob4,5:prob5,6:prob6}
    return dicctiradas

print(probabilidad())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen intento, ahora hagasmolo a la manera de Python. Al terminar el proceso verás como se calcula el porcentaje.

Tienes que acumular las tiradas en un diccionario, para lo cual nos conviene crear un diccionario inicializado. La llave es el dado (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 o 6) y el valor son las veces que ha salido:

```
def probabilidad():
    dicctiradas = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
```

Con este diccionario, tirar y contar se reduce a:

```
dado = random.randint(1,6)
dicctiradas[dado] += 1
```

Y si queremos repetirlo, lo ponemos en un `for`.

El resultado final es:

```
def probabilidad():
    dicctiradas = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
    for _ in range(1000):
        dado = random.randint(1,6)
        dicctiradas[dado] += 1
    return dicctiradas
```

Para calcular el porcentaje tenemos que sumar los valores del diccionario. Esto obviamente debe dar 1.000, por las condiciones del problema, pero si es necesario, puedes calcularlo recuperando los valores del diccionario en una  lista con

```
dicctiradas.values()
```

y aplicando `sum()` sobre el resultado.

Teniendo el resultado de la función, ahora podemos recorrer el diccionario obteniendo la llave y el valor de cada entrada con `dicctiradas.items()`, que retorna una lista de tuplas:

```
totales = probabilidad()
for k, v in totales.items():
    por = v * 100 / 1000
    print(f"dado {k}: {v} veces ({por:.1f}%)")
```

El cálculo del porcentaje `por` se puede simplificar, pero lo deje así por claridad.

#### Demo

```
import random

def probabilidad():
    dicctiradas = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
    for _ in range(1000):
        dado = random.randint(1,6)
        dicctiradas[dado] += 1
    return dicctiradas

totales = probabilidad()
for k, v in totales.items():
    por = v * 100 / 1000
    print(f"dado {k}: {v} veces ({por:.1f}%)")
```

produce:

```
dado 1: 159 veces (15.9%)
dado 2: 158 veces (15.8%)
dado 3: 167 veces (16.7%)
dado 4: 166 veces (16.6%)
dado 5: 162 veces (16.2%)
dado 6: 188 veces (18.8%)

Process finished with exit code 0
```